# To retrieve records having only two specific values

Tags: sql, squirrel-sql

Have the following Data in the table

```
Example Table
ID  Value
1   a
1   b
1   c
2   a
2   b
2   c
3   a
3   b
```

I need to retrieve records having ID with only two values a and b. 
So i am expecting only the Record with ID 3 .
Can anyone help me with the query

Comment: Please explain the problem more precisely.  Exactly what do you mean "two values A and B"?  One each?  Two in any combination?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could do something like

```
select
ID,
 sum(case when value = 'a' then 1
when value = 'b' then 1
else 3 end)

from 
table1
group by id
having
sum (case when value = 'a' then 1
when value = 'b' then 1
else 3 end) =2
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a0859/13)

Answer (score 0):

That will work:

```
select x.id from 
(
    select id from mytable where value = 'a'
    union all
    select id from mytable where value = 'b'
) x
group by x.id
having COUNT(*) = 2
and not exists (select * from mytable t where t.id = x.id and value <> 'a' and value <> 'b')
```